# How can I do to add more button with anthore slidedown Accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">S 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

I want to creat another button to section 1, but when I add it I couldn't click to slide it down! What is going wrong with my code?? I changed the code based on here!![enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol  and I add a tag call s1.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the section below your nested button isn't showing is because the `panel` from the parent button that contains it also has a `max-height` set (53px). You could account for that by either checking for parent containers with the class `panel` and increasing their `max-height` as well, or by creating a different function for nested buttons that sets the `max-height` of both the sibling and the parent `panel`.

```
<div class="panel" style="max-height:53px;"> <!-- Account for this one! -->
  <button class="accordion active">S 1</button>
  <div class="panel" style="max-height:86px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. If this resolved your question, please accept the answer. If not, provide a different answer or edit your original question. Thanks!